# Saving a json file to computer python

Tags: python, python-requests

Using `requests` in Python I am performing a GET, requesting a JSON file which I can later access and modify, tweak, etc. with the command `solditems.json()`. However I would like to save this JSON file to my computer. Looking through the requests docs I found nothing, does anybody have an easy way I can do this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can do it just as you would without `requests`. Your code might look something like,

```
import json
import requests

solditems = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json') # (your url)
data = solditems.json()
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: There's no good reason to deserialize and then re-serialize the JSON. Just write `solditems.content` straight out to file.

Comment: I was under the impression OP was going to be adjusting it before writing to file. "access and modify,tweak,etc". This is just meant as an example :)

Comment: just adding info : we don't need to create data.json first, because this answer will generate data.json automatically.

Answer (score 6):

Based on @Lukasa's comment, this accelerates @Jared's solution :

```py
import requests

solditems = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json') # (your url)
data = solditems.content
with open('data.json', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Answer (score 5):

This is also very easy with the standard library's new `pathlib` library. Do note that this code is purely "writing the bytes of an HTTP response to a file". It's fast, but it does no validation that the bytes you're writing are valid JSON.

```
import requests
import pathlib

solditems = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json') # (your url)
pathlib.Path('data.json').write_bytes(solditems.content)
```