# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 139811 (char 139810)

Tags: python, json, python-requests

What I'm trying to do here is to open values.json (which is https://www.rolimons.com/itemapi/itemdetails) but I get error on

```
values = json.load(file)
```

```py
r = requests.get("https://www.rolimons.com/itemapi/itemdetails")      
with open("values.json", "r+") as f:
  f.write(r.text)
f.close()

file = open("values.json")
values = json.load(file)
```

Comment: Did you try to load values from string inline in script?

Comment: The JSON as I download it now seems to be valid. Why are you writing it to a file? Why use `with` in one case but not in the other?

Comment: How did you create `"values.json"`? Did you mean to use `r.content`. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518937/saving-a-json-file-to-computer-python) seems relevant.

Comment: With "r+" the file will not be created if it does not exist yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
import requests
import json
req = requests.get("https://www.rolimons.com/itemapi/itemdetails")
values = json.loads(req.content)
print(values)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.